# SideNav with rsuite

Tags: reactjs, sidenav, rsuite

I want to create a sideNav in reactjs and I am using rsuite, but I am not able to make it work properly.
I have added my code to sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rsuite-sidenav-227q4?file=/src/SideNav.js)
Can anyone tell me how to style this properly and add route to the nav. Even if there is similar example that would do too.
I checked [this](https://github.com/rsuite/rsuite/tree/next/examples/with-react-router) example but that code also did not work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot to import the default style as describe in the [doc](https://rsuitejs.com/guide/usage/)
So you just need to add `import "rsuite/dist/styles/rsuite-default.css";` in your **index.js** file in your code sandbox.
[image: Edit rsuite-sideNav (forked)]